# TIMESTAMP format issue in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera, create-table

I have Hive table created from JSON file.

```
CREATE external TABLE logan_test.t1 (
   name string,
   start_time timestamp
   )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "timestamp.formats" = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
)
LOCATION 's3://t1/';
```

My timestamp data is in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`.

I specified SERDEPROPERTIES for timestamp format as given in the page.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps

Create statement executed successfully But `select *` failed with following error.

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '2017-06-01T17:51:15.180400'
>   for field 1: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Answer (score 2):

Jira [HIVE-9298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9298) in which `timestamp.formats` was introduced, says in the description that it is for LazySimpleSerDe. I did not find any other mention in the documentation that it was done for other SerDe.

The solution is to define timestamp as STRING and transform in the select.

Example for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` format:

```
select timestamp(regexp_replace(start_time, '^(.+?)T(.+?)','$1 $2'))
```

And this will work both for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` (normal timestamp) if there are both formats in data files.

```
timestamp(regexp_replace(start_time, '^(.+?)[T ](.+?)','$1 $2'))
```

Regex is powerful and you can parse different string formats using the same pattern.